# Javascript What is faster? Multiple OR in IF statements to target css, or one IF with multiple css targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set some code to function if the current page contains one of the following attributes below

```
if($('body[data-section="chicken"]').length || $('body[data-section="friedchicken"]').length){ 
    (function() {
      ///...
    }
}
```

Now i could simply do it like:

```
if($('body[data-section="chicken"],body[data-section="friedchicken"]').length){ 
    (function() {
      ///...
    }
}
```

Basically, a function to auto scroll down on the targeted pages.
But i'm curious! which one is faster to detect these targets?
and the reason I'm asking because i will be using more than 2 css selectors.

Comment: Have you profiled them? Do you expect there to be such a big impact on performance for you to actually care?

Comment: I doubt it makes a measurable difference, but why don't you test it?

Comment: is there a specific way to test? both functions same in my eyes lol xD

Comment: neither is the most efficient...get the element once and check the  attribute value only

Comment: Run then in a loop for A LOT of iterations do `var start = performance.now()` before and `var end = performance.now()` after, finally `console.log(end - start)`

Comment: Why not using "pure" Javascript. 
It's known to be a lot "faster" than jQuery, if you are up to the challenge.

Comment: This is a question you should be able to answer yourself without testing. "Is it faster to go in the kitchen take two cups and bring them in the living room or is it faster to take the cups separately  and go twice?"

Comment: There are plenty of useful methods for determining what code is faster in different circumstances, but that data will probably only be useful for a short period of time as browsers are constantly changing and optimizing different tasks. As such, questions like these are generally not useful. Useful questions on benchmarking topics generally have 4 things: 1. A hypothesis 2. A benchmark of both snippets of code 3. Conclusions drawn based on the benchmark, and 4: A practical, answerable question about what you do not understand about the benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is a concern, then skip the jQuery layer, address the `body` element directly, and only query for its *data-section* attribute once:

```
var attr = document.body.getAttribute('data-section');
if (attr == 'chicken' || attr == 'friedchicken') {
    // ...
};
```